# No data response getting data from iTunes api - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

In my Angular app, I am getting no response in the data coming back from the api? Code below, any idea's? I am getting result count as 0, when it should be 50?

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "api": {
      "target": "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake",
      "secure": true,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  api: string = 'api';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.api)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  public results = [];
  public data = [];


  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }
  private http: HttpClient
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getApi();
  }


  private getApi() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('JSON Response = ', JSON.stringify(results));
      this.data = results.results;
    })
  }
}
```

**JSON api structure**

```
{ 
   "resultCount":50,
   "results":[ 
      { 
         "wrapperType":"track",
         "kind":"song",
         "artistId":271256
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: Try plugging in your actual API endpoint into the http call and see if you get anything. From what it looks like, you're trying to execute an HTTP Request to 'api' and I doubt that will work. I'm aware you have a proxy setup, but maybe that's where your problem is. It also doesn't liek you're doing anything with the result. You're catching the eorr, but nothing else.

Comment: The thing is, if i put my api as `  api: string = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake';` it gives me CORS issue

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Proxy isn't going to fix that. They are blocking that on their end. You probably have to register your app with them so your url is whitelisted. I'm assuming they gave you some API key of some sort.

Comment: @Sole majority of the time CORS errors indicate the API is meant to be hit from a server and won't be allowed in the client.

Comment: I have built a similar app in vue.js and that did not have any CORS issue, so im sure I don't need an api key. If you type that URL in even you will get a result